# Uppercase sections and subsections on ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, capitalization

How can I insert `\MakeUppercase` inside the table of contents for sections and subsection?

```
\renewcommand{\l@section}[2]%
{\@dottedtocline{1}{.5em}{1.3em}%
 {{\bfseries\selectfont#1}}{#2}}
```

Comment: Are you using [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)? Also, what `\documentclass` are you using? Your redefinition of `\l@section` doesn't really help much since it doesn't provide any context.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 9):

This is a fairly general approach for changing the appearance of the entries in the table of contents.

The patch with `\xpatchcmd*` is just a way for avoiding copying the definition from `latex.ltx` and modifying it. The two places where `#7` appears in `\addtocontents` are replaced by `\@nameuse{format#1}{#7}` so we can define `\formatsection` and so on to do what we want to the title in the TOC.

```
\documentclass{article}

%%% Patching the kernel \@sect command
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\@sect}{\fi#7}{\fi\@nameuse{format#1}{#7}}{}{}

%%% for sections and subsections we want uppercase
\protected\def\formatsection{\MakeUppercase}
\protected\def\formatsubsection{\MakeUppercase}

%%% the other titles are left unchanged
\let\formatsubsubsection\@firstofone
\let\formatparagraph\@firstofone
\let\formatsubparagraph\@firstofone

%%% the following is necessary only if hyperref is used
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
    \let\formatsection\@firstofone
    \let\formatsubsection\@firstofone
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{This is a section}

\subsection{This is a subsection}

\subsubsection{This is a subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great, but how would you do it for `\section*`?

Comment: @PauliusK. `\section*` doesn't go to the TOC by default. Just add `\MakeUppercase` in the manually added `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: Well this is embarassing... Nevertheless, your answer is the cleanest sollution I've found for uppercasing sections in ToC. Doing it is way too difficult in LaTeX.

Comment: @PauliusK. Maybe classes such as KOMA-Script ones (`scrartcl`, `scrreprt` or `scrbook`) or `memoir` provide "native" methods (although I'm not sure). Titles in all capitals are heavy and, in my opinion, should be avoided.