# How to make section name uppercase in ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, capitalization, tocloft

Is there another way to change section names in ToC to uppercase besides [Uppercase sections and subsections on ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113681/uppercase-sections-and-subsections-on-toc)
Cause this one doesn't work for me very well.
Can it be done with tocloft package?

Answer (score 13):

#### Update: for a solution working with hyperref, see below.

An option, patching `\l@section`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{A test section}
\section{Another test section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your section titles contain math or commands (such as `\label`), it's best to use `\MakeTextUppercase` from the `textcase` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{#1}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{A test section $a=b$}\label{sec:test}
\section{Another test section with a reference:~\protect\ref{sec:test}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The solutions above won't work if the `hyperref` package is used. In this case, one can tamper with `\contentsline` (this borrows some code from **Heiko Oberdiek**'s answer to [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.text.tex/hyperref$20MakeUppercase/comp.text.tex/eiLmTiZjKcM/tl_H2ubg1ooJ) in `comp.text.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\def\contentsline#1#2{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname l@#1\endcsname\l@section
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {%
    \oldcontentsline{#1}{\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}%
  }{%
    \oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{A test section $a=b$}\label{sec:test}
\section{Another test section with a reference:~\ref{sec:test}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The above approach also works using `\MakeUppercase` instead of `\MakeTextUppercase`; if this is so, then `textcase` is not necessary.

Comment: Will that work with `hyperref` (most people tend to forget to mention that they also use `hyperref`

Comment: @daleif Good point! No, it won't work with `hyperref`. I'll add a remark about this.

Comment: @daleif now I've added a solution compatible with `hyperref`.

Comment: For some reason, this does not work with polyglossia and right to left languages. I tried with both Hebrew and Syriac. Any suggestions?