# Error - Table of contents in uppercase

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, compilation-error

I want to produce a table of contents using LaTeX like this image at which the table of contents list are all in capital:
[image]

So I wrote this LaTeX code:

```
%To make the sections in uppercase
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}% Sections use UPPERCASE in ToC
\makeatother
```

And this produced a strange error:

[image]

I don't understand the meaning of this error and I don't know how to solve it.

Any help ?

Edit: Here is my complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft,etoolbox}

%To make the sections in uppercase
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}% Sections use UPPERCASE in ToC
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} 
%\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\MakeUppercase{tableofcontents}} 

%To change the name of table of contents
\renewcommand\contentsname{\textbf{Table of Contents}} 
%\MakeUppercase{\tableofcontents}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

This is the first section.

Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...

\newpage

\section{Second Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a full but minimal example. From the error I can see that you're using `hyperref` which is a very important piece of information that you did not mention in your question. This is why we always ask for a full but minimal example, such that we can see which class and minimal preamble you are using.

Comment: Yes I am using hyperref package in my code, Is that the cause of the error ?

Comment: Among otherthings. Note that you really should not add formatting to `\...name` macros. A lot of macros assume that `\...name` macros are text with no formatting.

Comment: This might work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156917/3929, but `hyperref` has changed a bit since then. So I'm not sure if this is a good solution

Comment: Thanks :) It worked out for me

Comment: Why not use one of the answers to your original question (tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616292) posted on 22 September? You did not acknowledge any of the answers so why should any of the responders do anything more for you? --- GOM

Answer (score 1):

Since you've added [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), a minor adjustment is needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocloft,etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%To make the sections in uppercase
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\H@old@sect}{\fi #7}{\fi\texorpdfstring{\MakeUppercase{#7}}{#7}}{}{}% Sections use UPPERCASE in ToC
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%To change the name of table of contents
\renewcommand\contentsname{\textbf{Table of Contents}} 

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

This is the first section.

Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...

\newpage

\section{Second Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  
Etiam lobortis facilisissem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdiet mi necante...

\end{document}
```