# How to make remove Italics from TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I'm using `hyperref` for my dissertation's TOC and have subsection titles italicised using `\emph{}`. Is there a way I can retain the title formatting in the text, but make them appear unformatted in the table of contents?

For reference, I've tried what is suggested in the replies to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156916/how-to-make-section-name-uppercase-in-toc), and the following options using `tocloft` before the `\tableofcontents` command:
a) `\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\upshape}`
b) `\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont}`
c) `\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\textnormal{}}`
d) `\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\textup{}}`

They work fine to *add* formatting, but none of these help with removing the italics from the text. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please provide more information about "[I] have subsection titles italicised using `\emph{}`". E.g., do provide a couple of examples of actual `\subsection` directives. Please also tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: Use  `titlesec`  to have subsection titles italicized, with `\titleformat*{\subsection}{\itshape}` in the preamble.

Comment: @Mico I'm using the "report" class. 
Let's see if I've understood your question: I have 3 levels of titles  - `\chapter{X. Chapter Title}` -> `\section{X.1. Section}` -> `\subsection{X.1.1. Subsection}`.

Comment: @tex-mex-editor - Thanks for these pieces of information. The most important question remains: How exactly are you rendering the subsection-level headers in italics?

Comment: @Mico - Apologies. Using `\subsection{\emph{Subsection}}`.

Comment: @Bernard - This seems to have worked! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Always glad if I can help!

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve your formatting goal without loading any packages by repeating the section header, *without* the `\emph` wrapper, in the optional argument of the `\subsection` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip
\setcounter{chapter}{2} % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{3}

\subsection[Hello World]{\emph{Hello World}}

\end{document}
```